# Sewing pattern confusion

Tags: sewing

[image]

In this pattern step what do I do with the bodice lining?

Comment: I recommend adding the text of the step as an [edit] to the question including your notes. . Also if you can say where you got this pattern from as that can help in situations like this (even though you already have an answer the surrounding steps can still give context).

Answer (score 4):

In short, you **get the lining out of the way as much as possible**. Fold it up as far as it will go without causing the outer layer to wrinkle too much.

The instruction is to sew both skirt layers (outer and lining) to the outer layer of the bodice. The seam allowance gets pressed towards the bodice (upwards, from the finished dress perspective).

There should be a step (not necessarily the next, but probably soon) where the lining gets placed back to the original position again, the seam allowance folded inwards, ironed and sewn down, so that all excess material is hidded inside the bodice part. This makes the seam look nice from the inside as well and is more comfortable than having the seam allowance bits directly against your skin.

Comment: @Jessica Lah, I think that Stephie's response is what the pattern writer meant when s/he said to "Open out the bodice lining."  The idea is to pull it out from the inside of the bodice so that it is out of the way when you are sewing your bodice and skirt seams.  Not a very clear way to state things--but at least you will know what they are getting at if you ever use another pattern by this person again.